# sql server find the difference between rows of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table employees and for given empid, I would like to list the time, username and what has changed from previous time. Also for column 'req_type' I would like to write (normal) for 0 ,(important) for 1,(urgent) for value 2.

```
empid   Time                   req_type     token    requester   username    comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10      05-01-2014 10:04:00     0             10      grusel       ann
10      05-01-2014 11:11:00     1              8                   ben       check site www:\\abc.com
10      05-01-2014 10:10:00     0              2                   ann 
12      06-01-2014 13:00:01     0              2       Jeena       bill      check www:\\someerror.com
12      07-02-2014 14:00:00     1              6        Mike       bill
```

Select statement should give me 3 rows for empid = 10 like shown below

```
Time                    Username          Changed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
05-01-2014 11:11:00     ben          'req_type' updated from (normal) to (important), 
                                     'token' updated from 2 to 8,
                                     'requester' deleted,
                                     'comment' added check site www:\\abc.com
05-01-2014 10:10:00     ann          'token' updated from 10 to 2,
                                     'requester' added grusel
05-01-2014 10:04:00     ann           First entry
```

Similarly Select statement should give me 2 rows for empid = 12 like shown below

```
Time                    Username          Changed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
7-02-2014 14:00:00     bill           'req_type' updated from (normal) to (important),
                                      'token' changed from 2 to 6,
                                      'requester' changed from Jeena to Mike,
                                      'comment' deleted
6-01-2014 13:00:01      bill           First entry
```

Comment: Paste in you attempt and we can help you tweak it. Also you mentioned 2 RDBMS, which is it?

Comment: Please share your SQL, which you have tried so far.

Comment: Join the table to itself on the empid and the Row_Number() -1, and then apply your business rules to construct the "Changed" value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer we have to convert the final output to a space separated text by emp id

```
CREATE TABLE emp (id int , [time] datetime, req_type int, token int )

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 0,1)
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, GETDATE()-1, 1,1)
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (1, GETDATE()-2, 1,3)

;WITH cte AS
(

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time asc) rn  FROM emp 

),cte2 AS ( 
SELECT c2.*, CASE WHEN c.req_type != c2.req_type THEN 'Req changed from'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c2.req_type)+' to '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c.req_type)     ELSE '' END AS reqc, 
CASE WHEN c.token != c2.token THEN 'Token changed from' +CONVERT(VARCHAR,c2.token)+' to '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,c.token) ELSE '' END AS tokenc
 FROM cte c INNER join cte c2 ON c2.rn+1 = c.rn
 )

 SELECT id,time,req_type,reqc+tokenc AS changes FROM cte2
```

Comment: WITH cte AS gives compilation error. In the last statement what does reqc+tokenc means?

Comment: ok, instead of ;WITH cts AS the statement is now changed to select * from ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY td asc) rn  FROM employee 
) as cte, (   But now it gives syntax error over the select *, ROW_NUMBER statement